# App crash on 4th screen rotation (second time in landscape) with differing portrait and landscape layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app that uses two drastically different layouts for portrait and landscape.  The portrait mode is the main use case, where the user can control the application, and consists of a ListView with a few other views elements around it.  The landscape layout is just an informational view of whatever was last selected in the portrait view, and consists of a ViewPager filled with WebViews, and some of the same views as in the protrait mode, but not all of them .  When I run the app in debugging mode from Eclipse, and I rotate from portrait to landscape, back to portrait, and then back to landscape, it crashes on the last rotation to landscape every time (Stack printout in logcat below).  If I run the app on my phone without debugging mode, it does not crash.  The stack trace does not tell me much of why the crash happens. I try to make sure the views are not null where-ever they are used in the code.

My problem looks similar to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c9159dc972a15870#), but there's no further detail on a solution in that conversation either.  Can anyone give me a clue on what could be going wrong?  My guesses:
The app runs out of memory (some kind of memory leak occurs with each rotation, and that causes the crash after 4 rotations).

Or should I refactor my app and somehow make the two drastically different layouts two different activities?  The two layouts share just enough functionality to make me want to use the same activity.

**Logcat stack trace:**

```
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fonkmobile.player22tracks/com.fonkmobile.player22tracks.PlaylistActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:679)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:614)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at com.fonkmobile.player22tracks.PlaylistActivity.onCreate(PlaylistActivity.java:170)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     ... 12 more
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:115)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     ... 25 more
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/playlist_expanded_bg.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003c
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     ... 29 more
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:439)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:342)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:504)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:325)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
10-16 21:53:58.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4494):     ... 33 more
```

**My 2 layout files:**

**res/layout-land/playlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/playlistLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/black">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/webviewpager"/>

    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerAudioBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip" android:layout_marginBottom="117dip"
        android:handle="@+id/audiohandle" android:content="@+id/audiocontent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/audiohandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/audiocontent" layout="@layout/volumebar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerScrubbingBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dip" android:handle="@+id/scrubbinghandle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dip" android:content="@+id/scrubbingcontent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/scrubbinghandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/scrubbingcontent" layout="@layout/seekbar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerNowPlaying" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip" android:handle="@+id/nowplayinghandle"
        android:content="@+id/nowplayingcontent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/nowplayinghandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/nowplayingcontent" layout="@layout/nowplaying"></include>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerPlayBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dip" android:handle="@+id/playhandle"
        android:content="@+id/playcontent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/playhandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/playcontent" layout="@layout/playbar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**res/layout-port/playlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/playlistLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/black">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/webviewpager"
    android:visibility = "gone"/>

     <include android:id="@+id/djbar" layout="@layout/djbar" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/playlistview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:longClickable="false" android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/djbar"
        >
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/emptyplaylist"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </ProgressBar>

    <com.fonkmobile.player22tracks.widgets.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.fonkmobile.player22tracks"
        android:id="@+id/genredrawer"
        my:allowSingleTap="true"
        my:animateOnClick = "true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/genrehandle"
        my:content="@+id/genrecontent"
        my:direction="leftToRight">
        <include
            android:id="@id/genrecontent"
            layout="@layout/genrelist" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/genrehandle"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
             />
    </com.fonkmobile.player22tracks.widgets.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerAudioBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip" android:layout_marginBottom="117dip"
        android:handle="@+id/audiohandle" android:content="@+id/audiocontent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/audiohandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/audiocontent" layout="@layout/volumebar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerScrubbingBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dip" android:handle="@+id/scrubbinghandle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dip" android:content="@+id/scrubbingcontent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/scrubbinghandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/scrubbingcontent" layout="@layout/seekbar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerNowPlaying" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip" android:handle="@+id/nowplayinghandle"
        android:content="@+id/nowplayingcontent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/nowplayinghandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/nowplayingcontent" layout="@layout/nowplaying"></include>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerPlayBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dip" android:handle="@+id/playhandle"
        android:content="@+id/playcontent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@id/playhandle" />
        <include android:id="@+id/playcontent" layout="@layout/playbar" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/dragbar_left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null" android:id="@+id/imageDrawerArrow"
        android:layout_width="26dip" android:layout_height="100dip" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"></ImageView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I suspect a memory leak. How are you handling the configuration change in the activity? If you're using the default (let the system destroy and restart your activity), then there are lots of opportunities for memory leaks. Do you have any static variables in your activity class? Are you saving anything that might leak the old activity when the configuration changes? Perhaps post the code for those parts of your activity that deal with its life cycle.

Comment: I'm using the default, yes. No static variables, but lots of handlers registered on the views, and many of the views have background images that change during execution.  The OnCreate is rather large, I'm not sure what part of it to post really?  What should I watch out for to stop memory leaks, or is there another way to handle the rotation other than the default that will be safer regarding leaks?

Comment: And why doesn't it crash when not run as debugging, should that be a clue?

Comment: Handlers registered to views should be ok. Handlers registered with the system might cause a problem, but you don't mention that. You also make a good point about the debugger. So I've changed my mind. :) I now suspect a timing issue. Many of the emulators will actually generate **two** configuration changes in rapid succession when you switch orientations: one for the orientation and one for the keyboard. There have been several discussions about this in the android-developers group. Try configuring your manifest so that the activity handles keyboard changes. See if the crashes go away.

Comment: I finally decided to take control of the rotation myself and override onConfigurationChanged.  So I now have just one layout, and I hide the views not applicable to the current rotation.  That way the activity is not destroyed and created on every rotation, and the memory leak doesn't happen.  Not ideal, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

this happend because of memory leaking.

in the manifest, to the activity section, added:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the code for the activity, implemented:

```
//used in onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged() to set up the UI elements
public void InitializeUI()
{
    //get views from ID's
    this.textViewHeaderMainMessage = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewHeaderMainMessage);

    //etc... hook up click listeners, whatever you need from the Views
}

//Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
}

//this is called when the screen rotates.
// (onCreate is no longer called when screen rotates due to manifest, see: android:configChanges)
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
}
```